# Spring webclient pool is exhausted after sometime

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

Below are the different ways i tried to use web client to send a post, but each time the connection pool is exhausted after sometime. I get the below error.

I'm using `spring boot 2.7.3` version

Please help where are the connections not getting released.

The web client initialization code

```
@PostConstruct
public void getWebClient() {
    logger.debug("Initializing webClient..");

    ConnectionProvider provider = ConnectionProvider.builder("fixed")
            .metrics(true)
            .maxConnections(50)
            .maxIdleTime(Duration.ofSeconds(20))
            .maxLifeTime(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
            .pendingAcquireTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
            .evictInBackground(Duration.ofSeconds(30)).build();

    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create(provider)
            .wiretap(this.getClass().getCanonicalName(), LogLevel.DEBUG, AdvancedByteBufFormat.TEXTUAL)
            .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 10000)
            .responseTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10));

    this.webClient = WebClient
            .builder()
            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .build();
}
```

Code 1 :

```
public Mono<JsonNode> sendPostR(String url, JsonNode request) {
    String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    Instant start = Instant.now();
    logger.debug("Sending post request {} {} {}",url,request,uuid);
    return webClient.post().uri(url)
            .body(Mono.just(request),Map.class)
            .retrieve()
            .toEntity(String.class)
            .map(entity -> {
                Instant end = Instant.now();
                logger.debug("Time taken for request success{} {} ",Duration.between(start,end).toMillis(),uuid);
                if(entity.getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.OK) {
                    logger.error("Error: API returned with in-valid status code {} {}",entity.getStatusCode(),entity.getHeaders());
                    Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Error in sending post " + url));
                }
                String responseBody = entity.getBody();
                try {
                    return objectMapper.readValue(responseBody, JsonNode.class);
                } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                    logger.error("Error in parsing response body",e);
                    Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Error in parsing response body " + url));
                }
                return Utils.getNewObjectNode();
            }).switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> {
                logger.debug("Request completed with no body response {}",uuid);
                return Mono.just(Utils.getNewObjectNode());
            })).log();
}
```

Code 2:

```
public Mono<JsonNode> sendPostR(String url, Map<String,Object> params) {
    String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    Instant start = Instant.now();
    logger.debug("Sending post request {} {} {}",url,params,uuid);
    return webClient.post().uri(url)
            .body(Mono.just(params),Map.class)
            .exchangeToMono(response -> {
                logger.debug("response is {}",response.statusCode());
                Instant end = Instant.now();
                logger.debug("Time taken for request success{} {} ",Duration.between(start,end).toMillis(),uuid);
                if(response.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
                    return response.bodyToMono(JsonNode.class);
                }
                response.releaseBody();
                logger.debug("Error in hitting url {}",url);
                return Mono.error(new Exception("Error in sending post " + url));
            }).onErrorResume(WebClientResponseException.class, ex -> {
                Instant end = Instant.now();
                logger.debug("Time taken for request error {} {} ",Duration.between(start,end).toMillis(),uuid);
                logger.debug("Error in hitting url .... ",ex);
                return Mono.error(ex);
            }).doOnError(error -> {
                logger.error("Error in sending post request ",error);
            }).switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> {
                logger.debug("Request completed with no body response {}",uuid);
                return Mono.just(Utils.getNewObjectNode());
            }))
            .log();
```

Below is the code, which i use if i do not need the response. I use for fire and forget scenarios.

```
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Void>> raiseEvent(String url, JsonNode request) {
    String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    logger.debug("Sending post request {} {} {}",url,request,uuid);
    return webClient.post().uri(url)
            .body(Mono.just(request),JsonNode.class)
            .retrieve()
            .toBodilessEntity() ;
}
```

Error which i get when pool is exhausted.

```
2022-09-22 15:07:52,701 ERROR ? [parallel-1] Operator called default onErrorDropped
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: Pool#acquire(Duration) has been pending for more than t
he configured timeout of 30000ms; nested exception is reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.PoolAcquireTimeoutException: Pool#acquire(Duration) has been pending for more than the 
configured timeout of 30000ms
Caused by: org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: Pool#acquire(Duration) has been pending for more than the configured timeout of 30000ms; nested e
xception is reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.PoolAcquireTimeoutException: Pool#acquire(Duration) has been pending for more than the configured timeout of 30000ms
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:141)
        Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
        *__checkpoint ⇢ Request to POST http://api.call/track [DefaultWebClient]
Original Stack Trace:
                at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:141)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoErrorSupplied.subscribe(MonoErrorSupplied.java:55)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4397)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onError(MonoNext.java:93)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onError(MonoFlatMapMany.java:204)
                at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onError(SerializedSubscriber.java:124)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.whenError(FluxRetryWhen.java:225)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenOtherSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryWhen.java:274)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:415)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:251)
                at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.drain(EmitterProcessor.java:537)
                at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.tryEmitNext(EmitterProcessor.java:343)
                at reactor.core.publisher.SinkManySerialized.tryEmitNext(SinkManySerialized.java:100)
                at reactor.core.publisher.InternalManySink.emitNext(InternalManySink.java:27)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryWhen.java:190)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:201)
                at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect$ClientTransportSubscriber.onError(HttpClientConnect.java:308)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:201)
                at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.onError(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:158)
                at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.AbstractPool$Borrower.run(AbstractPool.java:413)
                at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68)
                at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
                at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.PoolAcquireTimeoutException: Pool#acquire(Duration) has been pending for more than the configured timeout of 30000ms
        at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.AbstractPool$Borrower.run(AbstractPool.java:413)
        at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68)
```

Comment: What code use your "sendPostR" method ? Is there a chance that it triggers more than 50 (your max pool size) queries concurrently ? If it uses Flux.flatMap, you can try setting a lower concurrency (default is 256, you can lower it to 20, for example).

Comment: @amanin the service has very low traffic, the pool size 50 concurrently requests is never reached. code use your "sendPostR" method used is mostly Mono.flatMap

Answer (score 1):

1. In "Code 1" `return` statements are missing for `Mono.error` but I have doubts it could cause mentioned issue.
2. There are several issues in "Code 2" with `exchangeToMono` usage that could potentially cause such behavior. According to documentation for `exchangeToMono`.

> After the returned {@code Mono} completes, the response body is automatically released if it hasn't been consumed.

You don't need to call `response.releaseBody()` explicitly but if you do, make sure it's part of the reactive flow you return because it returns `Mono<Void>` and will not be resolved.

3. Not sure why you need `exchangeToMono` that is typically used for advanced scenarios. From the first look, you can achieve the same with `retrieve().bodyToMono(...)` that is much safer.

```
webClient
    .method(POST).uri(url)
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(JsonNode.class)
```

The same can be done with "Code 1" to simplify logic in `map`.

4. To calculate duration better use `.onNext` and `.onError` that are designed for such "side-effect" operations.